# The inequality $\sum_{n=0}^{j}\binom{j}{n}x^{dn}\prod_{h=d-j+1+n}^{d}(1-x^h)\leq 1$

Tags: probability, inequality

I have a probability problem, and after a somewhat complicated argument I managed to prove it is equivalent to the inequality
$$f_{j,d}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{j}\binom{j}{n}x^{dn}\prod_{h=d-j+1+n}^{d}(1-x^h)\leq 1$$
where $d,j\in\mathbb N$ are parameters and $x\in [0,1]$. It looks like it ought to be elementary, but I'm finding it surprisingly difficult.

The thing catches my attention in that expression is that it looks like the binomial expansion of $(1+x^d)^j$ times something. I tried a couple of approaches related to that, tried to split into the product of two things and use Cauchy-Schwarz, etc. Numerically, it looks like $f_{j,d}$ is increasing for $d<j$ and has exactly one critical point otherwise, and also that for fixed $d$ and $x$, $f_{j,d}(x)$ is decreasing as a function of $j$.

So, is the inequality true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x\in [0,1]$ and $1-x^h$ is increasing  in $h$, we have

$$f_{j,d}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{j}\binom{j}{n}x^{dn}\prod_{h=d-j+1+n}^{d}(1-x^h)\leq \sum_{n=0}^{j}\binom{j}{n}x^{dn}\prod_{h=d-j+1+n}^{d}(1-x^d)= \sum_{n=0}^{j}\binom{j}{n}x^{dn}(1-x^d)^{j-n}=(x^d+1-x^d)^j=1.$$

So we have done.